# syntax error on flightInformation

Tags: java, arrays, class, syntax, boolean

I get syntax error after the second [][] saying I have to insert ".class" to complete expression
any suggestions for solving this ??

```
boolean[][] FlightInformation = new boolean[ID.length][flightCode.length];
FlightInformation[][] =  {{true,false,false,true,false},
                     {true,false,false,true,false},
                     {false,true,false,true,false},
                     {false,true,true,false,false},
                     {false,true,true,true,false},
                     {false,false,false,true,true},
                     {false,true,false,false,true},
                     {false,true,true,false,false},
                     {true,true,false,false,true},
                     {false,false,false,true,false},};
```

Comment: What language is this? Please add an appropriate tag to the question.

Comment: this is java language

Comment: I guess removing [][] on second line will not work as well.

Comment: the problem still on

Answer (score 1):

Can we do something like :

```
    boolean[][] FlightInformation = 
                        {{true,false,false,true,false},
                         {true,false,false,true,false},
                         {false,true,false,true,false},
                         {false,true,true,false,false},
                         {false,true,true,true,false},
                         {false,false,false,true,true},
                         {false,true,false,false,true},
                         {false,true,true,false,false},
                         {true,true,false,false,true},
                         {false,false,false,true,false}};
```

Comment: @Sarah Alofi : Can you please tell me what error you are getting now? Because this should work just fine.